# EC2 - Get a list of all instances started and stopped in last week

Tags: amazon-ec2

Is there a way to get a report of all the instances I've started and stopped in the past week? I'm more interested in seeing the individual running time of each.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AWS has a service called CloudTrail - http://aws.amazon.com/cloudtrail/

It basically logs all of the AWS API calls made to your account and writes them to an S3 bucket. You can parse the output and look for requests to start/stop instances, based on whatever filter you like.

As mentioned by @Brad, you can view historical info via the billing information. From the amazon console, click your username (top right) and choose "Billing and cost management". Select Reports-> AWS Usage reports.

Choose the Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud service, and the time frame you need.

Comment: This is perfect, but I didn't have it turned on until just now, so I can't see past data. You don't know of any Amazon metrics systems that are turned on by default, do you?

Comment: Added more info to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The only place that will have data other than CloudTrail is in the billing console.  It provides reports that explain charges.